# Unable to find Powerpoint COM Object with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} to set permissions

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

My web application is manipulating Powerpoint files. When I run it with my admin credentials it works, however when it is run by the Application Pool, it fails with error 80070005 Access is denied.

Been there, done that: all I need to do is giving permissions to the User associated to the Application Pool to the COM Object with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B}.

Except there isn't one. I cannot find it.

I have Office 365 installed on my machine, and the DLL I am using is called **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint**.

**Question**

How can I find the relevant Com Object? Is there an automated way, or do I have to manually create the keys in the Registry?

Comment: Obvious question, but did you log in as admin before attempting to locate that CLSID?

Comment: Also, I think there is a thing where you "install for all users" vs "install for this specific user?"

Comment: Yes, I logged in as administrator and for good measure run the Component Service application as Administrator.

Comment: Office is not designed to be used server-side; the Open XML file formats were designed specifically to make this unnecessary. You may find the information in this article helpful https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office